Why is the last Composable removed instead of the one at the specific index?
I have a StateFlow of objects in my ViewModel, in the UI I draw them in a forEach loop, I don't need a LazyColumn in my case, because all my items in zoomable and drawable. When I remove a certain item from the list by its id, it is removed correctly, but on the UI it seems that always the last Composable is removed instead of the one that was tied to the removed list item. How to fix this?
The state object data class has a @Stable annotation.
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = Color.Black)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onTap = {
                    viewModel.clickEmptySpace()
                }
            )
        }
) {

    allObjects.forEachIndexed {i, it->
        FrameItem(
            it,
            it.id() == selectedObj,
            click = { id ->
                viewModel.objectClick(id)
            },
            delete = { id ->
                viewModel.deleteObject(id)
            },
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun FrameItem(
    obj: CanvasObject,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    click:(Int)->Unit,
    delete:(Int)->Unit,
) {

    val frameObj = remember { obj as Frame }

    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    val transformabeState = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, panChange, rotationChange ->
        scale = (scale * zoomChange).coerceIn(0.3f, 5f)
        offset += panChange
        rotation += rotationChange
    }

    val frame = painterResource(Res.drawable.iphone_15_frame)


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .aspectRatio(frame.intrinsicSize.width / frame.intrinsicSize.height)
            .graphicsLayer {
                scaleX = scale
                scaleY = scale
                translationX = offset.x
                translationY = offset.y
                rotationZ = rotation
            }
            .transformable(transformabeState, enabled = isSelected),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
    ) {


                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(Res.drawable.shot),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                )

            }

           

}

How I delete an object from the state variable, which is working correctly:
fun deleteObject(id: Int){
     val currentList = emptyList<CanvasObject>().toMutableList()
     currentList.addAll(allObjects.value)
     currentList.removeAll { it.id()==id }
     allObjects.value = currentList
}


I do not understand what the problem is or what you are asking. Can you [edit] and clarify?

@KAMANCHO MORGAN Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of an answer.

Please use a key construct to tell Jetpack Compose the unique identifier for each FrameItem. Then Jetpack Compose can remove exactly the one FrameItem Composable corresponding to the removed  object from the allObjects List instead of removing the last one:
allObjects.forEachIndexed {i, it->

    key(it.id()) {  // Precondition: The id must be unique!

        FrameItem(
            it,
            it.id() == selectedObj,
            click = { id ->
                viewModel.objectClick(id)
            },
            delete = { id ->
                viewModel.deleteObject(id)
            },
        )
    }
}

Also, your deleteObject method seems not optimal. You can try to simplify it:
fun deleteObject(id: Int){
     val currentList = allObjects.value.toMutableList()
     currentList.removeAll { it.id()==id }
     allObjects.value = currentList
}

You can also consider to use the thread-safe update function and pass in the object to delete:
fun deleteObject(oneObject: OneObject) {
    allObjects.update { currentList ->
        currentList - oneObject 
    }
}

